# Server Sent Events In Firefox Not Working With AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, firefox

Currently I'm learning Server Sent Events. Everything is fine if I make a simple HTML application. But when I turn into AngularJS, the problem appears. Server Sent Events is not continually called in Firefox. It works only once. This problem doesn't happen in Chrome and Opera.

Is this some issues regarding AngularJS performance in Firefox? Or is there anything wrong with my code? Any answer would be very appreciated! Thanks.. :)

**Index.php**

```
<body ng-app='' ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Hapus</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in admin">
            <td>
                {{$index + 1}}.
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="{{x.Id}}" class="init" readonly>  
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea ng-keyup="myFunc($event, x.Id, 'Name')" class="init" ng-focus="edit($event)" ng-blur="noedit($event, x.Id, 'Name')">{{x.Name}}</textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea ng-keyup="myFunc($event, x.Id, 'Level')" class="init" ng-focus="edit($event)" ng-blur="noedit($event, x.Id, 'Level')">{{x.Level}}</textarea>
            </td>
            <td> 
                <button ng-click="sendDelete(x.Id)" class="btn btn-warning">Hapus</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-1.2.25.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                                function myCtrl($scope, $http, $window) {
                                    if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
                                        // Yes! Server-sent events support!
                                        var source = new EventSource("sse.php");

                                        source.onmessage = function(event) {
                                            msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
                                            $scope.admin = msg;
                                            $scope.$apply();
                                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += msg.Id + ". " + msg.Name + ". " + msg.Level + "<br>";
                                            console.log($scope.admin);
                                        };
                                    } else {
                                        // Sorry! No server-sent events support..
                                        alert('SSE not supported by browser.');
                                    }
                                };
        </script>
</body>
```

**sse.php**

```
<?php

  header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

  require_once 'koneksi.php';
  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
     $id = $_GET['id'];
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
  } else {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `admin`";
  }
  $stmnt = $dbh->prepare($query);
  $stmnt->execute();

  $output = "[";
  while ($row = $stmnt->fetch()) {
     if ($output != "[") {
        $output .= ",";
     }
  $output .= '{"Id":"' . $row["id"] . '",';
  $output .= '"Name":"' . $row["name"] . '",';
  $output .= '"Level":"' . $row["level"] . '"}';
  }
  $output .= "]";

  echo 'data: ' . ($output) . "\n\n";

 ob_flush();
 flush();
 sleep(1);

 ?>
```

Comment: look into using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel instead of `value="{{text}}"` and `<textarea>{{text}}</textarea>`

Comment: do you set `myCtrl` to be an angular controller anywhere? also have no `ng-app` defined?